# Why is "ssh -vT git@github.com" connecting/resolving to "127.0.0.1"?

Tags: git, ssh

I executed

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

and get

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [::1] port 443.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 443: Connection refused
debug1: Connecting to github.com [127.0.0.1] port 443.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 443: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host github.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Why is github.com resolving to localhost?

Comment: What does `curl -I -X GET https://github.com` give you?

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused

Comment: Please may you share the contents of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` relating to github?

Comment: Try whatever name resolver command you have on your host OS (`nslookup`, `dig`, whatever it might be on Windows) to see what IP address you get when looking up `github.com`. It should be one of GitHub's official IP addresses, but it seems as though you're getting `::1` (IPv6 local) and `127.0.0.1` (IPv4 local) for some reason. If the name resolver gets the same thing, the problem is your local name resolution. If the name resolver works, the problem is your ssh configuration somehow overriding the normal name resolver.

Comment: The `Applying options for *` entry (at line 21 of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) is notable since that could be where things are messed up. The diagnostic technique here, of using a non-ssh resolver lookup, will tell you whether that is the case, but you could also just inspect `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` directly.