# kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host: may be dns problem

Tags: git, github, ssh

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\xzb/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\xzb/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Connecting to github.com [::1] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\xzb/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\xzb/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

ping github.com

Pinging github.com [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

I try ssh -vT git@github.com and ping github.com in my terminal, above all is the result.Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Curiously identical behavior as seen very recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72391613/1256452). Is this a [common mode failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_cause_and_special_cause_(statistics)#Common_mode_failure_in_engineering)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pinging github.com [::1]...
```

It looks like "github.com" is resolving to a localhost address for some reason, and you're actually trying to connect to your local system. See if you have an entry for "github.com" in your /etc/hosts file (apparently this file will be [c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts on windows](https://gist.github.com/zenorocha/18b10a14b2deb214dc4ce43a2d2e2992)). Or else check with your local network administrators to see if they're doing some kind of network management that has this effect.